# How to make one column define table's height while the other will always have scrollbar?

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I have this problem at hand:

I have table with two columns. I want the left column to:

- Define height of the whole table
- *AND* at the same time have min-height of 300px

The second column will have much more lines than the left column but it will neither overflow nor expand the whole table (as the height of the table should be defined by left column and right column must **never** expand the height of the column).

So basically if first columns content is small (let's say two lines) the height of the table will be 300px and the right columns content will have scrollbar as its contents height is over 300px.

[image: small-left-columns]

Now next time you load the same page the first column will have more lines, so that their height is over 300px. The table's height will now get bigger so that it is as big as the content of the left column (and therefore left column will never have scrollbar) and right column will again be of appropriate size (same as left column) but again its content will get trimmed and the column will have scrollbar to view the rest of right column.

[image: big-left-column]

Could please anyone help me or point me in right direction? I've already spent two hours Googling and trying stuff but I just can't get it working. Also it doesn't have to be achieved with table only. Just divs are also fine. I only need two blocks of text next to each other, 100% width of parent div and height set by left column (while not being less than 300px).

Comment: For the right column you could try `overflow-y : scroll` on the "td" or add an another container (div) with that style/css property. Also this is not a homework solving site, you should first try to solve it yourself and... :)

Comment: Thanks for tip but unfortunately I already tried that. It will add scrollbar but the content will still expand the cell so the scrollbar will be useless (greyed out) while the whole table will have height of the right column.

Comment: Try to give it the same style as for the column on the left max-height, height. The only difference between them should be on the overflow/overflow-y.

Comment: The issue is that there is no max height or height. Only attribute in play is min-height set at 300px. The final height should be either 300px or the height of left column if that is more than 300px.

Now if i set overflow on right column it will not trim at 300px/height of left column but it will simply expand. This cannot be solved by simply adding overflow property on right column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a working example (adjust to your needs) https://jsfiddle.net/aymckoLt/22/

My solution uses a table and divs in the 2 columns:

```
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div> <!-- actually this div is unnecessary  -->
        <!-- add some of lines -->
      </div>
    </td>
    <td style="height:300px">
      <div style="height: 100%;overflow-y: auto;">
        <!-- add a bunch of lines -->
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Hope it meets your requirements.
*Late edit*
Trying to explain what happens ...

- Setting the height "fixed" on the right column plays the role of  "min-height" when the content of the left column it would be less then that height and at the same time gives a "boundary box" for the 100% of the div with the overflow.
- When the content of the left column, which has no boundaries/limits, it occupies more than that height it makes the cell (td) expand and with it it expands the cell on the right column also (kind of overriding the height specified) and most importantly it's taken in account by the height 100% of the div

Or to put it simpler ... it's the "magic" of table(s).

Comment: Indeed your solution works flawlessly! Thank you very much for your answer! It is most surprising for me that the height attribute should be set to 300px at the right column. I've always used min-height attribute and other ways which just never worked. Thanks again!